# How to override searchform.php using a plugin

Tags: wordpress, add-filter, search-form

I am trying to build a search form that looks a bit different from the default WP search box. I can edit the searchform.php for that, but I want it to be in form of a plugin, so that I can easily enable it and disable it at will. But the problem is that if WP finds searchform.php, it will use the form in that file, so no tricks like add_filter, add_action will work here. So, what I want to ask from folks here is: does there wxist some way by which I can achieve the above. i.e override the code of searchform.php

Also on a different note, if I name the search box to anything other than "s", then the code goes to index.php, instead of search.php. This, I have verified by putting debug echo's and other wierd statements.
What could be the possible reason for this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: After searching for the answer, I cam acrss some links that might be helpful. Posting these here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26268/how-can-i-replace-the-search-results-displayed-by-wordpress/26271#26271
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647604/wp-use-file-in-plugin-directory-as-custom-page-template
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18199/how-do-i-override-the-search-template-in-a-plugin/18203#18203

Comment: Some more: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65934/i-need-a-custom-search-page-to-lead-to-search-php-but-it-goes-to-index-php/65958#65958
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997743/make-plugin-override-template?rq=1
http://shinraholdings.com/363/3-wordpress-hacks-to-unlock-some-much-needed-features/4/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435931/wordpress-add-filter-get-search-form?rq=1
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-make-plugin-work-in-each-template-in-wordpress?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a hack. Not very good though, but works for me. So what I did is, in the activation filter of my plugin, I wrote the code to rename the original searchform.php (the one residing in the current theme folder) to searchform_orig.php   This way WP does not find searchform.php and so renders the searchform which I have hooked to the filter. Similarly, on deactivation part, I rename the file back to searchform.php. May not be ideal , but is working on y systems that I have tested. Though I would be interested in knowing loopholes/caveats in this approach.  Marking it as an answer ;-)